# Is it possible to extend Angular standalone component with another standalone component?

Tags: angular

I was trying to create an inheritance tree of standalone components but I was bogged down with issues like JIT compilation and waiting for `resolveComponentResources()`. I don't wait to enable JIT or import `@angular/compiler`.

The entire project is not using `@NgModule` decorator. It is leveraging the Routes and standalone components.

Sample Code looks like this,

```
@Component(
    {
        selector: 'page-drawer',
        template: '<div></div>',

        standalone: true,

        imports: (
            [
                PageComponent
            ]
        ),
    }
)
export class PageDrawerComponent
extends PageComponent
implements
OnInit,
OnDestroy
```

Note that all components are standalone. I added also those standalone components in the `imports` field of `@Component` decorator.

Can somebody please provide a complete sample code that is running exhibiting Angular's standalone component inheritance?

I'm using Angular version 16.

Comment: could you try to reproduce your issue on stackblitz?

Comment: @Andrei sorry I don't have time to do this, I've tried all possible combinations already. You can set up your own test on stackblitz that is working. I just need a sample Angular 16 code that does standalone to standalone component inheritance. Two components will do. ComponentA and ComponentB. Then you can share your answer here. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Standalone is the **new pattern** of Angular! And It's possible to have inheritance of Functions, Lifecycles and others properties!

And components works with same pattern as JavaScript inheritance!

### **From Angular's doc:**

*If a base class **defines a lifecycle method**, such as ngOnInit, a child class that also implements ngOnInit **overrides** the base class's implementation. **If you want to preserve the base class's lifecycle method, explicitly call the method with super:***

```js
@Component({ ... })
export class ListboxBase {
  protected isInitialized = false;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.isInitialized = true;
  }
}
@Component({ ... })
export class CustomListbox extends ListboxBase {
  override ngOnInit() {
    super.ngOnInit();
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

So with this statement, you can infer the behavior.

You can see more answers for this pattern on this page of **New Angular's Documentation**:

https://angular.dev/guide/components/inheritance

---

It is important to note that before, you need to **MIGRATE** your code to the **'Standalone'** type!

Here is the documentation:
https://angular.dev/reference/migrations/standalone

You should **run** the following command:

```bash
ng generate @angular/core:standalone
```

And execute it 3 TIMES, once for each option:
[image: Print of options to migration to standalone]

After all that, just code like I explained above.

**I made a small implementation that you can follow on CodeSandbox:**

MY CODE --> [SANDBOX IMPLEMENTATION](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/standalone-angular-example-2k3srt?file=%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fcomponent-b%2Fcomponent-b.component.html%3A6%2C1&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpizllb5000a356i68ebn9ln%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B48.20965842009423%252C51.79034157990577%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpizllb50003356it4eypskm%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpizllb50008356i97cphq6o%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpizllb50009356imr7jvukz%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B60%252C40%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clpizllb50003356it4eypskm%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpizllb50003356it4eypskm%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpj1ozku0003356iazjzjkuo%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A6%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A1%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A6%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A1%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fapp%252Fcomponent-b%252Fcomponent-b.component.html%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpj1ozku0003356iazjzjkuo%2522%257D%252C%2522clpizllb50009356imr7jvukz%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpizllb50009356imr7jvukz%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A4200%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpj14h4x007b356iukth0plf%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpj14h4x007b356iukth0plf%2522%257D%252C%2522clpizllb50008356i97cphq6o%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpizllb50008356i97cphq6o%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpj12r4g0037356ij3z3kj7q%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpizllb50004356ikgsknylx%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpj12r4g0037356ij3z3kj7q%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clpj10zus03d0eilxe8xbeurt%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Preview:
[image: Printscreen of Running Code]

Comment: Not working, either I get issues like I need to add a decorator, or `Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization`

Comment: @RicheveBebedor I updated my answer, added a second part, and included running code. In summary, you need to migrate your project entirely to Standalone. you can't have any 'NgModule'.

After doing that, if it still doesn't work, it's likely some Node.JS configuration or another issue.

Access my CodeSandbox, and you'll see the code running with inheritance functioning.

Answer (score 0):

It does allow inheritance

in parent component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Parent Comp</h2>
      <p>Shared Data: {{ sharedData }}</p>
    </div>
  `,
  standalone: true,
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  sharedData = 'Parent Data';

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Parent initialized');
  }
}`
```

Then in child component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from
 
'@angular/core';
import { ParentComponent } from
 
'./parent.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Child Component</h2>
      <p>Shared Data: {{ sharedData }}</p>
    </div>
  `,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ParentComponent], // Inherit from ParentComponent
})
export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Child initialized');
  }
}
```

inside app component

```
import { Component } from
 
'@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from
 
'./child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div>
      <app-child></app-child>
    </div>
  `,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ChildComponent],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {}
}
```

child explicitly imports the parent using the imports array in the @Component decorator.

I hope this will help.